# How to use groupBy, collect_list, arrays_zip, & explode together in pyspark to solve certain business problem

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark world.

Want to join two DataFrames `df` and `df_sd` on colum `days` While joining it should also use column `Name` from `df` DataFrame. If there is no matching value for `Name` and `days` combination from `df` DataFrame then it should have `null`. Please see below code and desired output for better understanding.

```
 import findspark

findspark.init("/opt/spark")

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

Mydata = Row("Name", "Number", "days")

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("DataFrame Learning") \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

mydata1 = Mydata("A", 100, 1)
mydata2 = Mydata("A", 200, 2)
mydata3 = Mydata("B", 300, 1)
mydata4 = Mydata("B", 400, 2)
mydata5 = Mydata("B", 500, 3)
mydata6 = Mydata("C", 600, 1)
myDataAll = [mydata1, mydata2, mydata3, mydata4, mydata5, mydata6]

STANDARD_TENORS = [1, 2, 3]

df_sd = spark.createDataFrame(STANDARD_TENORS, IntegerType())
df_sd = df_sd.withColumnRenamed("value", "days")

df_sd.show()

df = spark.createDataFrame(myDataAll)
df.show()
+----+
# |days|
# +----+
# |   1|
# |   2|
# |   3|
# +----+
# 
# +----+------+----+
# |Name|Number|days|
# +----+------+----+
# |   A|   100|   1|
# |   A|   200|   2|
# |   B|   300|   1|
# |   B|   400|   2|
# |   B|   500|   3|
# |   C|   600|   1|
# +----+------+----+
```

Please see below expected results from join

```
# +----+------+----+
# |Name|Number|days|
# +----+------+----+
# |   A|   100|   1|
# |   A|   200|   2|
# |   A|Null  |   3|
# |   B|   300|   1|
# |   B|   400|   2|
# |   B|   500|   3|
# |   C|   600|   1|
# |   C|Null  |   2|
# |   C|Null  |   3|
# +----+------+----+
```

Comment: will `df_sd` always be a small list of days? and what is your `spark version`?

Comment: Yes, df_sd will always be small list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **`df_sd`** will not be huge list, and you have **`spark2.4`**, you can do this by creating a new column in df with the list of days(1,2,3)and then use **`groupBy`**,**`collect_list`**, **`arrays_zip`**, & **`explode`**. The orderBy before the groupBy is there to ensure that the list gets collected in the right order.

```
df.show()
+----+------+----+
|Name|Number|days|
+----+------+----+
|   A|   100|   1|
|   A|   200|   2|
|   B|   300|   1|
|   B|   400|   2|
|   B|   500|   3|
|   C|   600|   1|
+----+------+----+
STANDARD_TENORS #->  [1, 2, 3] 
                #-> should be ordered



from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("days2", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in STANDARD_TENORS]))\
  .orderBy("Name","days")\
  .groupBy("Name").agg(F.collect_list("Number").alias("Number")\
                      ,F.first("days2").alias("days"))\
  .withColumn("zipped", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("Number","days")))\
  .select("Name","zipped.*").orderBy("Name","days").show()


+----+------+----+
|Name|Number|days|
+----+------+----+
|   A|   200|   1|
|   A|   100|   2|
|   A|  null|   3|
|   B|   300|   1|
|   B|   400|   2|
|   B|   500|   3|
|   C|   600|   1|
|   C|  null|   2|
|   C|  null|   3|
+----+------+----+
```

If you want to use **`join`**, you can do it in a similar manner:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_sd.agg(F.collect_list("days").alias("days")).join(\
df.orderBy("Name","days").groupBy("Name")\
.agg(F.collect_list("Number").alias("Number"),F.collect_list("days").alias("days1")),\
                      F.size("days")>=F.size("days1")).drop("days1")\
     .withColumn("zipped", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("Number","days")))\
     .select("Name","zipped.*")\
     .orderBy("Name","days")\
     .show()
```

**`UPDATE`**:

Updated In order to handle *any order whatsoever* or *for any value present* in **`Number`**.. I could have made the code a little more concise, but I kept it like that so you can see all those columns I used in order to understand the logic. Feel free to ask any questions.

```
df.show()
#newsampledataframe
+----+------+----+
|Name|Number|days|
+----+------+----+
|   A|   100|   1|
|   A|   200|   2|
|   B|   300|   1|
|   B|   400|   2|
|   B|   500|   3|
|   C|   600|   3|
+----+------+----+
#STANDARD_TENORS = [1, 2, 3]

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("days2", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in STANDARD_TENORS]))\
  .groupBy("Name").agg(F.collect_list("Number").alias("col1")\
                      ,F.first("days2").alias("days2"),F.collect_list("days").alias("x"))\
  .withColumn("days3", F.arrays_zip(F.col("col1"),F.col("x")))\
  .withColumn("days4", F.array_except("days2","x"))\
  .withColumn("day5", F.expr("""transform(days4,x-> struct(bigint(-1),x))"""))\
  .withColumn("days3", F.explode(F.array_union("days3","day5"))).select("Name","days3.*")\
  .withColumn("Number", F.when(F.col("col1")==-1, F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("col1"))).drop("col1")\
  .select("Name", "Number", F.col("x").alias("days"))\
  .orderBy("Name","days")\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi it works for me! If time permits  you may explain logic bit more that can help new learners like me (of courseI will going to do google on functions you have used :-) )

Comment: yes ofc. so first we orderyby to make sure we get right order to collect, then groupby Name to collect list by group and take our days list we created. now we ill have Numbers like [100,200] but your days list will always be [1,2,3]. So once we zip them using arrays_zip and explode them, the Number does not have a 3rd value, so 3 day will create a null value in Numbers automatically as we explode. Then we can select our columns from the zipped column. main logic resides in arrays_zip, it is crucial that u understand that.

Comment: complete docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html.

Comment: Seems one issue with solution. If you change input from C,600,1 to C,600,3 it gives wrong output.@Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi could you please check ?

Comment: check update. it will work for any case whatsoever.

Comment: Indeed! its been fixed! Many thanks @Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi